# How to drag and drop one element between two elements in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am using the following template for reference:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_drag_application.htm.
 I have two questions:

1)How to drag and drop one element between two elements in angularjs

2) how can I prevent auto float of the element and drop the element where exactly the cursor left in angularjs

Comment: refer this https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested

Comment: i am trying to do this without using frameworks